# Do ETF/ETNs invest directly in futures or forex, or do they just invest in stocks and bonds?

Tags: etf, foreign-exchange, futures, etn

Do ETF/ETNs invest directly in futures or forex? Or do they just invest in stocks and bonds?

Comment: There are also ETFs that physically hold commodities such as gold, silver, platinum, palladium, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Currencies**

ETFs that track currency movements are called [currency ETFs](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/currency-etf.asp). The simplest currency ETFs hold their foreign currency in a bank account.

**Futures**

Many synthetic ETFs use futures to track the price of an underlying. This is common in commodities ETFs, especially for commodities that are difficult and/or expensive to store long-term. An example would be a crude oil ETF that holds NYMEX futures to track the price of crude oil.